# Imprecise Rounding in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

Is there an easy way to make Python round using 32 bits instead of 64 bits? It would work in the same way as JavaScript's `Math.fround`, but I've ran circles in my head failing to come up with a solution.

Comment: It would help giving examples of what you are trying to do, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11523128/5236575?

Comment: Is there a reason you would need to round from 32 bits instead of 64 bits?

Comment: I'm using a seeded pseudorandom generator from a video game and the values were off because it wasn't being rounded from 32 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick way to do it is to assign the number to the value of a `ctypes.c_float` object:

```
from ctypes import c_float

d = 1.2345678901234567890
f = c_float()
f.value = d
print(d) # 64-bit double
print(f.value) # 32-bit float
```

This outputs:

```
1.2345678901234567
1.2345678806304932
```

Compared to `Math.fround` in JavaScript:

```js
console.log(Math.fround(1.2345678901234567890))
```

Answer (score 2):

try using numpy float32

```
np.float32(6.33333333333)
```

you should read this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690125/how-to-find-an-original-text-representation-for-lower-precision-float-values-in).

Comment: Unfortunately, np.round() and np.around() don't function the same as Math.fround(). Thank you though!