# Is there ways to avoid forced Format() rounding?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vb6, vba

**THIS IS ABOUT FORMAT() FUNCTION AND ITS BEHAVIOR**
NOT ABOUT MILLISECONDS OUTPUT!

Examples of time formatting are examples only but not more!

---

We have two sequential values returned by Timer(). After formatting we get rounded time measuring instead of timestamps:

```
? Format(36411.44921875 / 86400, "hh:nn:ss")
10:06:51
? Format(36410.984375 / 86400, "hh:nn:ss")
10:06:51 ' I'm waiting for 10:06:50 here
```

**Add_1:**
I'm not asked how to bypass this issue (like format separatly integer and decimal parts etc.). I'm interesting - is this the native behavior of Format()? Is there specific format string, for example, to avoid rounding?

**Add_2:**

> two **sequential** values

**Sequential is not important here**. I just found mentioned behavior on this sequence by eyes in log:

```
222 16-10-06 10:06:51.449 36411.44921875 0.421428810402199
221 16-10-06 10:06:51.984 36410.984375   0.421423430266204
```

Sorry for my english...

**Add_3:**
In my case, I still process the integer and fractional parts separately. So I did so:

```
Format$(Int(dDate * 86400) / 86400, "hh:nn:ss")

'543 16-10-06 12:03:21.214 43401.21484375 0.502328875506366
'542 16-10-06 12:03:20.667 43400.66796875 0.502322545934606
```

However, this is just a trick and not for all cases it is convenient...

**Add_4:**
Apparently, my English is not good enough :(

The problem is that the use of Format() corrupts timestamp!
When taking the timestamp only rounding down is used.

For example, we have now 23:49:59.981765
What is timestamp with hours accuracy? 23. Not 00.
With minutes accuracy? Yes, 23:49, but not 23:50!
With seconds - 23:49:59.
Milliseconds? 23:49:59.981

Not to be confused with timestamps taking and time intervals measurement... In the second case, you can round off as anything...
.

**Add_4.1:**
Playing with **23:49:59.981765** from Add_4 above:

```
? Format(CDate((TimeValue("23:49:59") * 86400 + .981765) / 86400), "hh")
23 ' *** !!! NOT ROUNDED !!! ***
? Format(CDate((TimeValue("23:49:59") * 86400 + .981765) / 86400), "hh:nn")
23:50
? Format(CDate((TimeValue("23:49:59") * 86400 + .981765) / 86400), "hh:nn:ss")
23:50:00
```

**Conclusion**

The Format() behaves as he likes.

**Some values it rounds, some - not. By which rules?** It is a top secret.
For what reason it uses **standard rounding instead of bank rounding in VB(A)?** It is a top secret No. 2.

.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
**P.S.**

First of all - many thanks to Comintern (RotFront!) and Gustav for usefull clarifying of touched problems.

However, my question (statement) - **The Format() behaves as he likes** - is open still.

It was my big-big mistake when I said the words "Timer()" and "Milliseconds". And even when the title was clarifying all ignored it. I ask in second time - please, forget "Timer()", "Milliseconds" and your catterpillars of digits after dot.

Really there was the only remark from Comintern (RotFront!) on which disclosure I was waited for:

> *The Date type itself is specified with second precision, and Format in this context works on Date types.*

In other words, not Format(), but internal (im- or explicitly) convert to Date datatype is the cause of around. And I was ready to be satisfied with this, but:

**A. As say** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221646.aspx

> *The variant time resolves to one second. **Any milliseconds in the input date are ignored**.*

We see that milliseconds not only **not ignored, but rounded instead of!**

**B. How_1 they are rounded?**
Comintern (RotFront!) is absolutelly right when say:

> *It is impossible to consider rounding of only a second without looking at it in context of the full time.*

In my case the rounding chain breaks on the hours. But it assumed, that all of time components, i.e. seconds, minutes, hours, days, monthes, years are equitable...

**C. How_2 they are rounded?**
Comintern (RotFront!) wrote:

> *Windows uses the round half away from zero method1.*

Which "Windows"? Who is "Windows"?
I know, that VB(A) has a single rounding function - Round() - and it use "Round half to even". All internal rounding at data types conversion use it too. But not "half away from zero".

And only Format(), upstart, white crow, use "half away from zero"... Why?

**D. Resolution_1...**
And what means "resolution" applying to data type? 500 mcs, 1 sec - there are only a two-three sources where this "resolution" figures sounded... I have the Date==Double data type on the hands. I can't understand - how they can be dropped from continuous numerical line - this 0.5-1 sec...

**E. Resolution_2...**
Maybe all this misunderstanding is because only internal timers - Date(), Now(), Time(), Timer() - are considered as an only possible sources of timestamps? In my case I get external csv log with reliable authentic timestamps and Format() distorts this excellent data for me.

And even in case of directly Timer() using. I have two counts on display from QueryPerformanceCounter and from GetSystemTimeAsFileTime. For visually evaluate their validity I format both as "hh:nn:ss.000" and place near them  Timer() data which distorted by Format()... 
.

Comment: I'd record the start time and then add `timeserial(0,0,INT(36411.44921875 -36410.984375))`

Comment: I show 36411.44921875 for example only :) It is not associated, but independent counts.

Comment: Here is an article about using milliseconds in Access, no idea if it's useful for you: http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046

Comment: @Andre, thanks a lot. I have not seen this article still. It will be good reading for evening. Actually, I'm quite confidently with high precision timers like QueryPerformanceCounter, GetSystemTimeAsFileTime etc.

Comment: Are you asking if `Format` supports fractional seconds? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: @Comintern, Rotfront! I know it and it was not in my question :) Fractional seconds supported in Excel sheet UDFs only... however forced rounding is present there too.

Comment: The answer to that is also no. The `Date` type *itself* is specified with second precision, and `Format` in this context works on `Date` types. There is no reasonable exception that it should be expected to handle time values with "higher" precision.

Comment: @Comintern: Not exactly. While there is no official support nor documentation for split seconds, milliseconds can safely be handled within the entire range of Date. See link in my answer.

Comment: @Comintern, I, in turn, expect you to utter anything intelligible about _The Date type itself is specified with second precision_ ;) Rotfront! No, why all did stand on this f..g milliseconds? The point is not in them ...

Comment: @Gustav (and OP) [See this for the specified precision](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshpoley/2007/12/19/datetime-formats-and-conversions/)? A `Date` datatype is a VT_DATE.  It has a 500ms resolution. Whether or not you can get *system* date times and *calculate* to doubles is irrelevant.  When you move the decimal point 3 places to the right, precision decreases.  Even if you can represent them with a float accurately across the whole supported date range, `Format` shouldn't be expected to be more precise than the data type it's formatting.  Hope that is "intelligible" enough for you.

Comment: @Comintern, sorry for previous comment. It shold be to Herb, not for you. However, you wrote above about seconds, now - about 500 msc. OK :) But, how does this relate to format rounding?! Look to Add_4.1 What about "When taking the timestamp only rounding down is used"?! Look to Add_4. Flooder detected? Rotfront!

Comment: @Comintern, moreover, I help you. 1 sec is right too: [The variant time resolves to one second. Any milliseconds in the input date are ignored.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221646.aspx). However, the next question arises: written IGNORED, but really ROUNDED. I'm just waiting for this IGNORED

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know only - is there ways to control rounding, produced by
>   Format() internaly?

No.

But by custom methods, you can handle milliseconds as you wish.

You can study this article on the topic and download code for all common tasks including methods for display of decimal seconds or milliseconds:

[MS Access Can Handle Millisecond Time Values](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046)

Please get back if you have questions related to this.

**Addendum**

I see a lot of confusion here which has side-tracked your question. So, to get back to this, if you wish to get rid of the millisecond part of your values (449 and 984 respectively) to obtain a display of "full" seconds only, you can use this function (taken from the link above) to kill the milliseconds:

```
Public Function DateTimeRound( _
  ByVal datTime As Date) _
  As Date

' Returns datTime rounded off to the second by
' removing a millisecond portion.

  Call RoundSecondOff(datTime)

  DateTimeRound = datTime

End Function


Private Sub RoundSecondOff( _
  ByRef datDate As Date)

' Rounds off datDate to the second by
' removing a millisecond portion.

  Const clngSecondsPerDay       As Long = 24& * 60& * 60&

  Dim lngDate             As Long
  Dim lngTime             As Long
  Dim dblTime             As Double

  ' Get date part.
  lngDate = Fix(datDate)
  ' Get time part.
  dblTime = datDate - lngDate
  ' Round time part to the second.
  lngTime = Fix(dblTime * clngSecondsPerDay)
  ' Return date part and rounded time part.
  datDate = CDate(lngDate + lngTime / clngSecondsPerDay)

End Sub
```

Now you can apply Format to the resulting values.

**Addendum 2**

Corrections to your PS:

> The Date type itself is specified with second precision, and Format in
>   this context works on Date types.
>
> In other words, not Format(), but internal (im- or explicitly) convert
>   to Date datatype is the cause of a round.

While it is true that data type is specified down to seconds only, this hasn't blocked for the ability to operate with millisecond precision. Thus, your "other words" should be exactly opposite:

*Format(), not an internal (im- or explicitly) convert, is the cause of a round.*

Your link to *LPSYSTEMTIME* adds a lot of confusion as this is about Windows time which has nothing to do with data type Date of VB(A). You should forget all about this as it is internal to Windows and of no use in VBA except for special cases  where you can access it via the Windows API (as you will se demonstrated in my millisecond article).

> In my case the rounding chain breaks on the hours.

Yes, that will happen if the millisecond part of the value exceeds 500. You can use my function above to avoid that.

> I know, that VB(A) has a single rounding function - Round() - and it
>   use "Round half to even". All internal rounding at data types
>   conversion use it too. But not "half away from zero".

You miss many details here. *Round* and all the Cxxx functions (like CLng) perform *Banker's Rounding* or "round to even". On the contrary, as the only function of VBA, *Format* performs a normal 4/5 rounding as you learned in school. Thus, it will consistently round decimal seconds to the nearest integer.

You ask why, and there is no answer to this other than "by design".

If you are really interested on the topic of rounding, note that the native *Round* is quite buggy. You can read all about this, including documentation and functions that cover all aspects of rounding for any numeric data type of any value here at Github:

[VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

> And what means "resolution" applying to data type?

It means the lowest difference between two values. That is exactly 1 ms for the extreme values of data type Date: `100-01-01 00:00:00.000` and `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999`, thus is valid for the entire range of Date. Within a small range of months around `1899-12-30` you can go to microseconds and, for a range of a few hours, even to nanoseconds.

> I can't understand - how they can be dropped from continuous numerical
>   line - this 0.5-1 sec...

Well, luckily this is not the case, so there is nothing to understand.

> In my case I get external csv log with reliable authentic timestamps

That's life, and that is one of the reasons I wrote that article back then on how to handle such cases.

> Format() distorts this excellent data for me.

True, because Format was not intended for it. But, again, using my function to cut off the split seconds, you can use Format as is.

As for *Timer*, I can't see where it comes in for your case. It is really not intended for anything else than its name implies - it returns a *Single* with a resolution of 1/64 second, and is quite handy for quick timing of a function or a running query. That's all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that you were involved in this article. :)

Comment: It's old stuff, and I revamped it recently, but the guts of it still holds true.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** - There *is no rounding rule* for seconds.  It depends on the entirety of the time.

A Date type is stored internally as a Double, which in turn is an [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating point number with 52 bits of mantissa.  The radix has to accommodate values high enough to represent the largest date that is valid for a VT_DATE (December 31st, 9999).  Expressed in days since epoch, that comes out to 2,958,465. That means at least 7 digits have to be accommodated to the left of the decimal.

Assuming that the data type accounts for the greatest supported radix, that gives 13 digits without loss of precision to the right of the decimal (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484553/4088852) for where that number comes from, and the Wikipedia article on [Machine Epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for a more detailed explanation).  Assuming that the radix is based on the actual number stored (5 digits in your examples), then you get 14 digits of precision.
Several methods of rounding are actually defined in the IEEE specification, but Windows uses the [round half away from zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) method<sup>1</sup>.

Keep in mind that this happens a *all* levels of formatting a Double to a time, because it is defined as fractional days, and each component results in a repeating fraction:

- One second is `1 / 24 / 60 / 60`, or .0000115740740740741. Note that VBA rounds this value after 19 digits.
- One minute is `1 / 24 / 60`, or .000694444444444444. Note that VBA rounds this after 18 digits.
- One hour is `1 / 24`, or .0416666666666667.  Note that VBA rounds this also, but at a 16 digit precision.

None of these calculations need to account for a radix, but more importantly *they are all comingled with each other*. That means any precision loss in *any* of the hour, minute, or second components can effect all of them. ***It is impossible to consider rounding of only a second without looking at it in context of the full time.***

Now, let's take a look at your code here:

```
Format$(Int(dDate * 86400) / 86400, "hh:nn:ss")
```

You mention that you are evaluating the results of the `Timer()` function, so let's assume for the sake of argument that `dDate = Timer()`.  The first thing to point out is that `Timer` returns a `Single`, *not* a `Double`.  That means the precision of the value returned can only be assumed to be accurate to roughly 7 decimal places (the radix is fixed at 1). In order to coerce this into a Date, you have to scale it and it gets implicitly converted to a Double in the process.  But, the entire calculation can't be assumed to be more precise than 7 decimal places. Every additional calculation you perform has the possibility of introducing rounding errors based on precision.

So, the only concrete solution is to not rely on format for precision scales beyond 1 second, and roll your own formatting function or use an alternate storage mechanism (@Gustav points in one direction for this) if you need more precision.

<sup>1</sup> See [Inconsistent Rounding of Printed Floating-Point Numbers](http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/).

Comment: "There is no rounding rule for seconds. It depends on the entirety of the time." This is not so. There is, in fact, a very strict rule for (visual) rounding of seconds, and that is the count of milliseconds: 0 to 500 is rounds down, 501 to 999 is rounds up. Thus, it is totally unrelated to the nature of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @Gustav - Read the answer again. Saying "the count of milliseconds: 0 to 500 is rounds down, 501 to 999 is rounds up" is ***exactly the same thing*** as saying that it uses the round half away from zero method for partial seconds. The floating point is completely related, because you can't extract a base 60 number from a base 10 number without using floating point numbers.

Comment: You have got this wrong, sorry. The rounding method chosen is _by design_, not due to the behaviour of floating point numbers which, indeed around zero, has resolution enough to go to the millisecond.

Comment: @Gustav - The key phrase there is "around zero". VAR_DATE isn't limited to "around zero". If you'd like to substantiate the claim that the "rounding method chosen is by design" or how you can determine what 500ms even *is* using a VAR_DATE without performing a floating point operation on it, I'll look forward to seeing an edit to your answer.

Comment: I certainly did - back at 2008-09-09 - see the link in my answer. It documents and demonstrates how to handle and calculate data type Date with millisecond precision from `100-01-01 00:00:00.000` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999` - it will even show why the epoc of `1899-12-30 00:00:00.000` is not "just some date" but a very cleverly chosen value; the old design team of Access 1.0 knew what they did.

Comment: The epoc [sic] date wasn't chosen by the Access 1.0 team.  [It was chosen by the Lotus 123 team, and was partially a bug.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html)

Comment: @Comintern, RotFront! Thank you very much for such detailed explain (no irony at all). Please, look to P.S. in my original post.

Comment: @Comintern: That is on a very different matter. The date range of _Lotus 1-2-3_ was only 1900 to 2099, thus not related to 1899-12-30. And the blog your link to is not about the epoc date but about the compatibility issue with Lotus 1-2-3 regarding the day count in year 1900.